# Weird rsync behaviour

Tags: rsync

I wrote a backup script for automating my backups using `rsync`. For maintenance purposes I stored all of the necessary options in an array and used it on the actual `rsync` call.

For better visibility each option got its own line inside the array declaration. However, I made the grand mistake of terminating each line with a `/` instead of the correct `\`.

The `rsync` command that my script then run basically ended up being something like this:

`rsync --verbose / --recursive / --archive / --progress source_folder destination_folder`

The next mistake was not to use `--dry-run` but thankfully I was quick enough to Ctrl+C the script while it was still building the file list and having lots of errors saying `Permission denied (13)`.

This leads me to my question: If you have tried the above command (with `--dry-run`) you might have noticed that `rsync` is traversing everything from `/` as I guess `/` is (mistakenly?) used as source and destination.

However, if I try to run
`rsync --verbose test1/ --recursive test2/ --archive / --progress source_folder destination_folder`, instead of `test1` and `test2` being interpreted as source and destination, `rsync` again starts traversing from `/`. Why is that?

I don't know if `source_folder` and `destination_folder` are completely ignored or used later on since I quit the script each time while `rsync` was building the file list.

Also, what could have gone wrong if I hadn't aborted the initial run where `/` is used as source and destination? Would `rsync` overwrite each file with itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are telling rsync to do is to use the options `--verbose --recursive --archive --progress` with source folders `test1/ test2/ / source_folder` and destination folder `destination_folder`, if that helps already. (Additionally, you might want to consider pulling off the trailing slash in the test folder names, to get the complete folder, not just the contents)